# Java Plugin Table Color T

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a view with a table that is populated with an array list. The problem is that I can't solve an error regarding the table foreground.

Piece of code:

```
(1) Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.SINGLE);
(2) table.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

error on (2) : The method setForeground(Color) in the type control is not applicable for the arguments (Color)

I've imported java.awt.color 
Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing AWT and SWT. The `setForeground` method of an SWT table needs a `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color` reference. Call it like this:

```
Display display = table.getDisplay(); // or whatever can get you the display reference
table.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
```

Comment: How can I set only the selection foreground ? The ideea is that I want to color the selected row on mouse selection.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Was my answer (or greg's) not understandable? If so, what did you not understand?

Comment: The answer was understandable and it worked. I was wondering, how can I set the selection foreground or maybe the default blue on every selection for the entire row ?

Comment: Ok, maybe you should ask that as another question.

Answer (score 2):

`Table` is an SWT control and does not use anything from `java.awt`

You should be importing `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color` - but this does not have any predefined colors.

To get predefined colors in SWT use:

```
Display display = table.getDisplay();

Color color = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
```